# Apache Tomcat websockets server side messages

Tags: tomcat, websocket

I have successfully implemented an simple echo server example for tomcat websockets. now I need to send continuous messages to the client from my server. How do I achieve this??

Present server side code

```
package org.playjava.websocket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.catalina.websocket.MessageInbound;
import org.apache.catalina.websocket.StreamInbound;
import org.apache.catalina.websocket.WebSocketServlet;
import org.apache.catalina.websocket.WsOutbound;

public class SimpleEchoServlet extends WebSocketServlet {

    @Override
    protected StreamInbound createWebSocketInbound(String string, HttpServletRequest hsr) {
        return new SimpleEchoInbound();
    }

    private static final class SimpleEchoInbound extends MessageInbound {

        public SimpleEchoInbound() {
            super();
        }




        @Override
        protected void onBinaryMessage(ByteBuffer message) throws IOException {
            getWsOutbound().writeBinaryMessage(message);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onTextMessage(CharBuffer message) throws IOException {
            getWsOutbound().writeTextMessage(message);
            getWsOutbound().writeTextMessage(message);
            getWsOutbound().writeTextMessage(message);
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start a thread in the constructor of SimpleEchoInbound and call getWsOutbound().writeTextMessage() in that thread.

By the way, you are working with Tomcat's proprietary WebSocket API that is deprecated in Tomcat 7 and has been dropped entirely in Tomcat 8. You should switch to the JSR-356 Java WebSocket API that is fully supported in both Tomcat 7 and Tomcat 8.